# How to draw sound in android

Tags: java, android, audio, trigonometry

I'm creating an app on android in java, very simple, which has a button that on click play a sound.
I want to create a sort of canvas to draw something like sinusoide of music.. i hope i've been clear.. 
Do you know something about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this [Api](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.html) Demp it may help u.

Comment: i can't use it in api level 7 :( what can i do?